# Why is System.nanoTime() incorrect in the beginning of iterations?

Tags: java, loops, time

I've noticed a pattern with System.nanoTime(). Everytime I begin an iteration, the nanoTime() gets hugely incorrect for a couple of laps until it finally stabilises.

If I for instance run the following code:

```
public class TimeTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long prev = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++);
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(time - prev);
            prev = time;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

[image: Test result 1]

To eliminate the possibility of System.out.println(String) messing with the result, I can also run the following test:

```
public class TimeTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] difs = new long[10];
        long prev = System.nanoTime();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++);
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            difs[i] = (time - prev);
            prev = time;
        }

        for(long l : difs)
            System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image: Test result 2]

The initial delay could possibly be explained by assuming that the beginning of an iteration (in this case the for-loop) is taking some extra time to initialize before the loop begins. However, since the second lap supposedly also takes a long time to execute, we can believe that it might not be the for-loop after all.

So my question is simply, what is causing this initial delay when using System.nanoTime() together with iterations?

Note: I've also tried different types of iterators, but the problem remains.

Comment: Don't blame `nanoTime()`. The timings are real.

Comment: What Java version JDK or JRE do you use for the test? I get nearly the same results for all loops. (JDK 1.7, Win 7 64bit)

Comment: JDK 8.0, JRE 1.7.0, OS X Mavericks 32bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks to me like the [JIT warm up time of the JVM](http://stuq.nl/weblog/2009-01-28/why-many-java-performance-tests-are-wrong)

> The Java HotSpot compiler kicks in when it sees a ‘hot spot’ in your
>   code. It is therefore quite common that your code will run faster over
>   time! So, you should adapt your testing methods.
>
> The HotSpot compiler compiles in the background, eating away CPU
>   cycles. So when the compiler is busy, your program is temporarily
>   slower. But after compiling some hot spots, your program will suddenly
>   run faster!

Comment: On a multicore processor running single-threaded client code, the JIT compiler doesn't steal any time from the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++);
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(time - prev);
    prev = time;
}
```

I note two main phenomena you may be overlooking:

1. The first time you call `println`, there is probably some initialization work going on;
2. your inner loop (over `j`) will be optimized away *in its entirety* once the code is JIT-compiled.

In the stable state you are left with some 30 microseconds per lap, which is about what it takes for one `println` to do its work.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrianAgnew already mentionned, it is caused by the Just in time warm up of the JVM.

You could solve this using `-XX:CompileThresold=1` to force java to compile everything the first time it runs. It would slow down the startup of your program, but `System.nanotime()` would probably work properly.

---

What is Just in time compilation ?

> JIT compilation is a combination of the two traditional approaches to
>   translation to machine code – ahead-of-time compilation (AOT), and
>   interpretation – and combines some advantages and drawbacks of
>   both.[1] Roughly, JIT compilation combines the speed of compiled code
>   with the flexibility of interpretation, with the overhead of an
>   interpreter and the additional overhead of compiling (not just
>   interpreting). JIT compilation is a form of dynamic compilation, and
>   allows adaptive optimization such as dynamic recompilation – thus in
>   principle JIT compilation can yield faster execution than static
>   compilation. Interpretation and JIT compilation are particularly
>   suited for dynamic programming languages, as the runtime system can
>   handle late-bound data types and enforce security guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to JIT, if you deactivate it for the `main` then measures are consistent.

```
java -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,TimeTest,main TimeTest
```

gave me

```
CompilerOracle: exclude TimeTest.main
### Excluding compile: static TimeTest::main
8886537
9020980
8841953
8817411
8948350
8942021
8728320
8598453
8585024
8627902
```

Note that the impact of this is to slow down the computations by a factor at least 100! JIT is a very efficient technology...